# Can someone explain the difference between minecraft maps and worlds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have two Minecraft Bukkit SMP server instances on my host and I understand there's a default "world" included with each instance. I've read about multi-world support in future versions of Bukkit or Minecraft, but at the moment, I believe I'm stuck with a single "map" for each world.

Am I missing something or am I currently limited to a single world (and a single map) on each server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no difference between "map" and "world."<sup>1</sup>

You can generate new maps/worlds for your server by renaming the "world" folder that is in the same directory as your server.  When you start your server, it will see that there isn't a world named "world", and will create one.

<sup>1</sup>Note: There is now [a map object](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map_%28Item%29) in the game.

Comment: @ John: Thanks. Each server normally will host a single world is what I'm understanding. Also, when people currently refer to a map, they must be talking about a custom, pre-built world.

Comment: @phatjim Each server can only host a single world *at a time*. You can change what world it is hosting. I had forgotten about that use of the term "map." That sounds correct.

Answer (score 2):

The world is the terrain around you, the actual blocks that make up what you see and interact with. **A map is some 2D representation of the world** (*Aside: This applies to the real world too!*). There are already programs to generate a variety of different maps, from straight top-down maps to cave-maps, isometric maps, etc.

In Minecraft 1.6 there will be a new map item which can be crafted to provide top-down mapping functionality in-game.

Answer (score 1):

Bukkit does support multiple worlds, but as far as I know you need a plugin that implements this, such as [MultiVerse](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/misc-tp-fun-multiverse-v1-6-4-netherportals-to-multiple-worlds-766.3707/) or [NetherGate](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/tp-fun-nethergate-v0-56-just-like-single-player-803.3430/). I suppose that it supports multiple worlds from a plugin developer's perspective; it doesn't do it itself out of the box.

Comment: Note that vanilla is getting Nether functionality in the next release, and presumably Bukkit will support it natively immediately.  There are still tons of Bukkit plugins for multiple worlds/cross-server warps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it is referring to a 'world' as a space where people can play, and a 'map' as the terrain data which occupies said world.