# Where is the world saved on a Minecraft server, and how do I back it up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've found some related answers: I think I get [maps and worlds](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23006/can-someone-explain-the-difference-between-minecraft-maps-and-worlds), and I now know [where single-player saves are located](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/where-are-my-minecraft-saves-located). I'm not sure I completely understand [this answer about copying a multiplayer map to single-player](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/how-do-i-copy-a-minecraft-multi-player-smp-map-to-single-player), but in any case, I'm only concerned about multiplayer survival mode:

Suppose I'm running a Minecraft server on Windows for myself and friends. Which files should I save to "back up" the state of the world at a particular point?

For example, I might want to do this just when I need to shut off the server, to be sure not to lose anything; to save one world and go back to it later, while starting a new one for now; or to restore the world from an earlier state, when we hadn't flooded the house with lava yet.

Comment: If you run your minecraft server from within a Dropbox, Google Drive, or Microsoft Skydrive folder, everything will be backed up automatically.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The world data, which also includes player inventories, is saved to a folder in the current working directory of the server.

The name of said folder depends on the `level-name` setting in `server.properties`, and defaults to `world`. Thus, you can start a new world and toggle between the saves by simply changing this setting.

Vanilla server commands related to saving/backups:

- `/save-all` - forces the server to save.
- `/save-off` - disables saving. You **should** definitely execute this before making a backup of a running server to ensure that the server doesn't save while you're copying, which could result in a corrupt backup.
- `/save-on` - re-enables saving.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think to disable saving while making a backup.

Comment: i saved the server to my desktop so were will the directory be??

Comment: Do you know if there is there a way to run the `save-off` and `save-on` commands from a batch job?

Comment: @Mike If you're just looking for an automated way to make backups, you can look into plugins to do this such as [Bukkit Backup](http://bukkitbackup.com/) or [other Bukkit backup plugins](http://plugins.bukkit.org/curseforge/#ti=Backup). I would also recommend looking into [mcrcon](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admin-rcon-mcrcon-remote-connection-client-for-minecraft-servers-new-ipv6-support.70910/), which lets you run commands remotely.

Answer (score 4):

Within the directory you're running the server from, there should be a `world` folder. In that directory are all of the files that your server needs to run. The most important thing to backup would be the `region` folder within the `world` folder, which actually contains all the "block information". Another folder within the `world` directory is the `players` folder, which stores informations about the players that connect (inventories, etc).
*(Note that the directory is only named `world` if you haven't changed the `level-name` property in `server.properties`.)*

This information is true of a Vanilla and a Bukkit multiplayer server.

**TL;DR**: backup the entire `world` directory.