# Java Minecraft Structure Block transfer to a paid server my friend has

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

i have my Structure Block all ready to go and found the file (took awhile ) and now im trying to figure out how to get the file into a hosted sever my friend has

Answer (score 2):

You should put it in a corresponding folder in the world save folder of the server. Normally, the server's subfolder `world` corresponds to the folder with world name in `.minecraft/saves` although the [folder name can be changed in server properties](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25031/where-is-the-world-saved-on-a-minecraft-server-and-how-do-i-back-it-up)

For example, my experimental world is called 1_15_redstone, and the structure I saved was called `inot`. So, I take the file:

`.minecraft\saves\1_15_redstone\generated\minecraft\structures\inot.nbt`

and upload it to the server, placing it in the server's subdirectory

`world\generated\minecraft\structures\inot.nbt`

It's entirely possible the subfolder `generated` and its subfolders won't exist on the server - they are only created as a first structure block's structure is saved, so either create them, or just create and save any dummy structure in game on the server.